Dialogs don't appear in 22.04
I am having trouble with Firefox.  The symptoms are:

dialog boxes don't appear for things like save-to-pdf (the final dialog to specify the pdf filename)
drag and drop dialogs (popups) don't appear for things like Google Photos

I have checked several times- popups are enabled.
I don't know what else it could be.
I have also tried Chrome- it does not come up at all.
I have also tried GNOME Web- it comes up but shows no content in the browser window
